# Translate SQL to Laravel Eloquent: join with between

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a query I need to perform (or an alternative to that query) through eloquent. The query in general works like a charm, but it does not seem to translate to Laravel's eloquent builder. I'm aware of Laravel's `DB::select()` function, but would much rather make this fit.

The part of the query where I get stuck is the Join between:

```
LEFT JOIN event_override_hours 
ON event_normal_hours.event_id = event_override_hours.event_id 
AND '".$timestamp."' BETWEEN event_override_hours.start_date AND event_override_hours.end_date
```

One of the things I tried is using raw queries:

```
->leftJoin('event_override_hours', function($join) use ($timestamp) {
        $join->on('event_normal_hours.event_id', '=', 'event_override_hours.event_id')
        ->on(DB::raw('? BETWEEN event_override_hours.start_date AND event_override_hours.end_date', [$timestamp]));
})
```

But it turns out that the query builder raw function is not raw at all. It tries to make something of it and translates that to:

```
BETWEEN event_override_hours.start_date AND event_override_hours.end_date = ``
```

Apparently it assumes that with an "AND" it needs an extra variable like a "WHERE". It makes sense, but it's just not what I'm looking for.

I've also looked into extending the builder, but that all just seems much of the same.

I would love to get a workaround for this within the parameters of eloquent if I missed something. A custom query builder would be great to. Or maybe you know of an alternative for "BETWEEN" based on what you see here.

I'm using Laravel 10 and MySQL 8

Comment: Can you pls share your full database query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't find anything that made this possible. But it seems the answer is very ugly and hacky, but save enough if you clean your input:

```
->leftJoin('event_override_hours', 'event_normal_hours.event_id', '=', DB::raw('event_override_hours.event_id 
    AND "'.$timestamp.'" BETWEEN event_override_hours.start_date AND event_override_hours.end_date'))
```

The trick is to use the last entry as a complete raw to do anything you want.